# Concurrent create table if not exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
if not exists (select * from sysobjects where name='cars' and xtype='U')
    create table cars (
        Name varchar(64) not null
    )
go
```

If I run the above batch from multiple concurrent transactions will it work without errors everytime or can there be a race between the if and create statements?

Comment: Better question is why you need multiple batches to be creating (and presumably using) the same permanent table. Yes - race condition.

Comment: Each tran wants to insert a different row in the table. I don't want to create the table unless I really need to. It may be a bad pattern but it make the rest of the system easier if it works.

Comment: @HariKrishnaS this is an x/y problem i.e. the problem you are attempting to solve here is not the real problem. If you explain why/how this apparently makes the rest of the system work better you would get a better answer. Because its very unlikely that creating tables like this on the fly is the best solution.

Comment: XY problem for sure - create the table once where you (or preferably the dba / experienced database designer) can assign permissions, indexing, etc. and adding the appropriate maintenance activities (if any) to the system and the system documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by race condition that multiple transaction will have concurrently checked that the table do not exist then concurrently try to create the car table, then yes. But why worry, one will succeed the others will fail. That said, I think you should review your strategy on how you do things. More details are necessary to provide further advice.

Comment: I am playing around to see if this will work. It has worked for me so far but week it work with more load too. Shouldn't such things be documented somewhere?

Comment: @HariKrishnaS such things are documented, but you're probably looking in the wrong place. You need to understand the bigger picture, being that every SQL statement in SQL Server runs in its own implicit transaction, hence locks last that long. For longer locks you need an explicit transaction, and often explicit locks.